# jQuery version of MooZoom

Tags: jquery, mootools, zooming

I want to replicate the functionality of "MooZoom" in jQuery as seen on the [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) website (click the images in the bottom right).  Specifically I want to recreate the functionality that when you click on the image it:

- Shows a loading indicator and pre-loads the image
- Animate from the thumbnail's current position to the full sized image in the center of the screen

Is there anything that mimicks this functionality?

Comment: I just saw something like that the other day..  I'll try to look for it when I get home.

Comment: try: [http://fancybox.net/](http://fancybox.net/)